# React select with nested data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select, optgroup

I am trying to make a nested select optgroup and tried the following,

```js
const data = [
  {
    sectorId: 5,
    sectorName: "Sector One",
    departments: [
      {
        deptName: "Production",
        jobtitles: [
          {
            JobTitleID: 167,
            DepartmentID: 51,
            JobName: "Production Manager",
            Deleted: false,
            SortOrder: 5
          },
          {
            JobTitleID: 178,
            DepartmentID: 51,
            JobName: "Production Supervisor",
            Deleted: false,
            SortOrder: 3
          },
          {
            JobTitleID: 449,
            DepartmentID: 51,
            JobName: "Senior Wall Panel Designer",
            Deleted: false,
            SortOrder: 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        deptName: "Design/Engineering",
        jobtitles: [
          {
            JobTitleID: 294,
            DepartmentID: 52,
            JobName: "Senior Truss Designer",
            Deleted: false,
            SortOrder: 5
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    sectorId: 24,
    sectorName: "Sector Two",
    departments: [
      {
        deptName: "Consulting",
        jobtitles: [
          {
            JobTitleID: 191,
            DepartmentID: 92,
            JobName: "Saw Shop Supervisor",
            Deleted: false,
            SortOrder: 1
          },
          {
            JobTitleID: 474,
            DepartmentID: 92,
            JobName: "Senior Truss Designer - Part Time",
            Deleted: false,
            SortOrder: 11
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        deptName: "Administration",
        jobtitles: [
          {
            JobTitleID: 461,
            DepartmentID: 114,
            JobName: "Sawyer",
            Deleted: false,
            SortOrder: 7
          },
          {
            JobTitleID: 278,
            DepartmentID: 114,
            JobName: "Service Manager",
            Deleted: false,
            SortOrder: 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <select>
      {data.map((levelOne, i) => (
        <optgroup label={levelOne.sectorName} key={i}>
          {levelOne.departments.map((levelTwo, j) => (
            <optgroup label={levelTwo.deptName} key={j}>
              {levelTwo.jobtitles.map((job, l) => (
                <>
                  <option key={job.JobTitleID} value={job.JobTitleID}>
                    {job.JobName}
                  </option>
                </>
              ))}
            </optgroup>
          ))}
        </optgroup>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"> </div>
```

Sorry the above snippet has errors and you can also look at the working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-0v81j)

This doesn't provide nested group of data and it stops with single level itself.

**Current output:**

```
Sector One
Sector Two
```

**Expected output:**

```
   Sector One

     Production

       -> Production Manager

       -> Production Supervisor

       -> Senior Wall Panel Designer

     Design/Engineering
    
       -> Senior Truss Designer

   Sector Two

     Consulting

       -> Saw Shop Supervisor

       -> Senior Truss Designer - Part Time

     Administration
    
       -> Sawyer

       -> Service Manager
```

Here only the jobtitles will be option, so as per the above data, the list that has `->` will alone be option and others will be label.

So only using optgroup I have tried the above code, But don't know what mistake I am doing which results in not populating the data as per the expected result.

Kindly please help me to solve the above issue and make the above example work as like the expected output.

Adding any other **react based** library to achieve this also welcomed.

Comment: The sandbox you gave is working right?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan, Yes it is working but not displaying the result like I have mentioned in the question (Expected Output) .

Comment: From what i see it shows the -> ones as options and the rest are labels, maybe I'm not getting your requirement

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Are you checking in chrome? Because I came to know that this issue occurs only in chrome it seems.

Comment: Oh sorry i'm checking it on firefox

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan, No issues.. Do you have any idea why it happens like this? Or do you have any suggestion of including any library to make the nested dropdown labels and options?

Comment: Actually as its a browser issue better mention that as well, i think someone in this forum can suggest a library

Answer (score 0):

1. optgroup may not be nested, so only the sectorName is displayed;
2. you can try to use the react-selector library. Here is an example [react-select nested groups](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-v3-nested-groups-d2ds5?file=/example.js) that I've found with nested levels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But why for the last two options doesn't allow to select individual items? The options that comes under ```Corporate (Total)``` and ```Product (Total)``` doesn't allow to select indivdual items.. Rather it makes the selection to all the options under it..